# Python Image RGB list to 2D Array python 2

Tags: python, arrays, image, list

I successfully converted my image to RGB values using:

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open(imageDir, 'r')

pix_val_rgb = list(im.getdata())
```

Of course, this only give me an 1D array. Is there any built in function that converts 1D arrays to 2D, or would this be a type of task that I will have to program on my own?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Use something based on numpy for nice and efficient operations. There you would use reshape if even needed, as scipy or scikit-image, both using numpy arrays keep images internally always as numpy arrays.

Comment: Thanks! I will try that and see how it goes.